# tvOS UITableView causes error on Apple TV but not simulator

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos, apple-tv

I have a UITableView on my controller.  It is in focus when the controller shows the page.

When the focused row changes, I want to update a UITextView(called _appText) in the code below).

This all works fine in the simulator, but when I run on the Apple TV I get the following error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '_ignoreFocusUpdateIfNeeded should never be YES at the beginning of a focus update.'

I'm running tvOS version 9.01 on the Apple TV

Here's the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUpdateFocusInContext(UITableViewFocusUpdateContext *)contextwithAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator*)coordinator{
NSInteger ourRow=context.nextFocusedIndexPath.row;

NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[_appIconNames objectAtIndex:ourRow] ofType:@"html"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

NSAttributedString *thisString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
_appText.attributedText=thisString;
}
```

The line which causes the error is:

```
NSAttributedString *thisString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Can't figure out why it works in the simulator but not the Apple TV itself.

Comment: are you using the computer keyboard to navigate using the simulator? I have the same error as you on a different project but only when I navigate using the "Apple TV Remote" on the simulator. I don't know how to fix this issue yet but maybe the occurrence is related to that.

Comment: also, I'm having this problem because I'm using an NSAttributedString to display a NSHTMLTextDocumentType document as well.. it might be a bug related to focus and UITextView or NSAttributedString

Comment: I am also running into this.. Any updates on it? I am not sure what is up but it only happens when I am trying to put HTML into an attributed string like you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**Objective-C:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   _appText.attributedText=thisString;
}
```

**Swift:**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   _appText.attributedText = thisString
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 3**:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   _appText.attributedText = thisString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you're looking for:
No idea why this is needed, but I had the same problem, and this did solve it...
Borrowed from Banana's, the real issue was the conversion of the string, not the assignment.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSAttributedString *thisString=[[NSAttributedString alloc] 
    initWithData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
    options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, 
              NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
    documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
});
```

Comment: This may answer the question but it would be a much better answer if you formatted the code so it could be read without needed to scroll it sideways. It would be nice to see the whole answer without any sideways scrolling.